# Python Conditionals

Tags: python

Apparently:

```
if board[0][0] == X and board[1][1] == X and board[2][2] == X:
    pass
```

Is not the same as:

```
if board[0][0] and board[1][1] and board[2][2] == X:
    pass
```

How can I summarize this statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == X:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if (board[0][0] and board[1][1] and board[2][2]) == X: 
    pass
```